# How to Generate APK within Android App programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin, apk

I have a request to develop an application (lets call it XYZ) that after selecting some stuff an APK should be generated with that stuff.

Is it even possible to generate an APK with another app? I imagine it should be possible with some scripting but this should work as a standalone, which means that every XYZ should be able to create APKs with some previous picked content.
If it is, how exactly?

I tried looking around but couldn't find anything.

Thanks guys

Comment: So.,.. you have to develop Android Studio, Gradle, the compiler and the rest of the android tools like zipalign, dextool and the rest of the android toolset? Good luck.

Best chance is to take a look at how android was developed earlier, in Eclipse with Android Developer Tools, before gradle. You have a reasonable chance of rolling something like that out by yourself.

Comment: technically it is possible what you are trying to do but you would have to re-implement large parts of the Android SDK in your APK generating app. If you are alone such an app could be ready in few years if you are working on it every day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work by "selecting some stuff". Creating the actual APK is one of the last steps of what is quite a complex process. Let's take a look at this overview, not really recent and a bit simplified, but still valid (*image credit: MIT*):

[image: APK build process]

So basically you would need the whole bunch of tools to run locally as an app,  ̶w̶h̶i̶c̶h̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶n̶o̶t̶ ̶p̶o̶s̶s̶i̶b̶l̶e̶.̶ which probably could be implemented by dedicated expert developers, but the effort would be insane, especially when compared to the benefits.

To sum it up: you cannot create an APK from some random "picked content". You would need the source code along with required resources and configuration files + a build server that would run Gradle to compile, assemble and package everything.

Comment: I would be careful with "not possible". Usually it is just a question how much time you are willing to invest. In this case it is IMHO a question how many years of your life you are willing to invest in building such an app.

Comment: apologies, I implicitly assumed that the OP has neither the required skills nor several years of their life to spare  Edited to reflect that technically it might be possible.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot generate an apk file within a standalone android app. You need a backend to generate the apk. Basically you need to create an API which will run some scripts and use the android sdk to create and send the apk.

Comment: ps: I am currently working on a similar application which allows the end user to create a UI of the app and build the apk using a backend. I am using react native to build the app and node express for backend and mongodb for database. In this app the end user can select and edit some stuff and hit the build button which will then build the source code in the backend and start building the apk using gradle and send it to the end user. The only thing is that the generated app (apk) will be focused on the UI part and not on the functionality (just some click to navigate).

Answer (score 0):

To build an APK your PC (or phone) needs the Java Development Kit, i don't think this can be run on a normal phone. Also this is quite large so it would make your own app 10+ Gb.

As suggested above you could generate the APK on a backend and download it to the users device.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to go deeper in your client business context to understand his real business problem and find out better ways to achieve it rather than this.

Apk should be built, signed and installed from the phone. Phone should support installation from unknown sources. At this moment a build is done by one gradle command, but under the hood it covers plenty amount of things which should be within your mobile device to make it run.

Also it is important to keep in mind rising security requirements in the modern Android versions, many things could not been achieved on non-root device.

Considering all of this it might be enough for your client to go with another idea.